# Paperclip image generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a Rails 4 application with a model containing a paperclip attachment :

```
has_attached_file :avatar
```

When I try to view my image into a view, I use this code :

```
image_tag(user.avatar.url)
```

It generates this code :

```
<img src="/system/users/avatars/.../foobar.png%3F1418229557" alt="...">
```

The image `foobar.png%3F1418229557` doesn't exists ; but the image `foobar.png?1418229557` exists, and should be the right url.

In console,

```
u.avatar.url
> foobar.png?1418229557
```

I use paperclip since years and I never get this issue. Do you have any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`%3F` is the url encoded version of `?`. Are you just passing the string to the image tag helper? If you are doing anything different, than maybe using `...url.html_safe` will help

Comment: That was my first temptative. It keeps the `%3F`.